# django channels share instance variable between group users

Tags: django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I am developing a online game on django, for real time connection I am using channels but unfortunately for every user I have a separate instance of game.

What I want is, for first user I start the game with object of `StartGame` and want to use this same instance object for other users also, because I want to share current state of game.

How can I, share game instance with other members of that group only ?

One thought I have is to save the current state of game in a file and save the path of file in db and for another user retrieve the saved state of game and play his/her chance and again save, but is that efficient and correct way to do so ?

What is actual scenario for online games ?

**Update**

I have achieved it but is it correct way or secure ?

I created a global variable `GAME_POOL = {}` and stored the instance of Game with key `channel_group_name` for first user then for other users check if `GAME_POOL` have existing value for `channel_group_name` then set `self.game = GAME_POOL['channel_group_name']` and its working.

But again it is secure and good way to achieve this ?

I am deleting this after game finished.

Comment: how about storing the game state directly in the DB? why store in a file first?

Comment: it's difficult for me because game have too many models and saving all on db for every move and for a lot of users will useless load on db... best option I am seeing is sharing the instance of that game between group users... if it is achieved then it will be better.

Comment: @Ken4scholars please check the update

Comment: If you want to store the state on memory and not DB, what if the number of groups gets too large and bloats the memory? Do you need persistence as the game worker may experience problems and shutdown? All these depend on your use case and it's questions you have to answer yourself. There's no single correct way.

Comment: @Ken4scholars you are correct but the program is already taking 20 mb in ram and when I save the object instance its of 5kb, so I thought rather than making load on db I can have this instance in ram only because its of only 5kb and already taking 20mb for processing. Please tell me is it a correct way to achieve this ??

Comment: Like I said, there's no single correct approach, so I can't tell you it's the correct approach. That you will have to decide for yourself. I can only tell you some factors that should be considered as I already list above. I personally don't see how that will be too much load on the DB if you have your queries optimized. Also is 5kb for one group? The number of groups is bound to grow right? If you are Ok to store it in RAM at this point then that's OK, but it may outgrow the RAM in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store the game state in RAM (despite the limitations mentioned by Ken4scholars in the comments) you could also move the shared variable in a [middleware](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html#custom-authentication) as follows:

```
from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware


class GameStateMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner
        self.game_states = {}

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        query = dict((qp.split('=') for qp in scope['query_string'].decode().split("&")))
        game_id = query.get('game_id')

        if game_id not in self.game_states:
            game_states[game_id] = {}

        scope['game_state'] = self.game_states[game_id]
        return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
```

Inside the consumer the shared variable would then be available in `self.scope['game_state']`. As it is passed by reference you could also write to it, however, then you need to take care of synchronization (for example by also injecting locks into the scope).